BeautifulSoup code not returning more than 20 results?
I'm new to BeautifulSoup and have a little experience with Python. I'm using BeautifulSoup for web-scraping, specifically reviews of books on Goodreads. When I use this code, it only gives me the first 20 reviews, never anything beyond that. The page loads at 30 reviews when it's first opened (not counting the "show more reviews" button)
This is my code -
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/26114463/reviews?reviewFilters={%22workId%22:%22kca://work/amzn1.gr.work.v1.lSjSf2r-G6D1advk_kunEg%22,%22after%22:%22NjAwMDEsMTU4Njg4NDczNzY1MQ%22}"

html_text = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')

print(soup)


This is probably because the page uses javascript.  When you load the page in a real browser it is able to process the javascript.  But requests is not a browser; it does not process javascript.

the reviews are loaded from a graphql endpoint, you can try scraping it instead

Here is an example how you can use their Ajax graphql API to get all reviews from the page:
import requests

api_url = (
    "https://kxbwmqov6jgg3daaamb744ycu4.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/graphql"
)

headers = {
    "X-Api-Key": "da2-xpgsdydkbregjhpr6ejzqdhuwy",
}

payload = {
    "operationName": "getReviews",
    "query": "query getReviews($filters: BookReviewsFilterInput!, $pagination: PaginationInput) {\n  getReviews(filters: $filters, pagination: $pagination) {\n    ...BookReviewsFragment\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n\nfragment BookReviewsFragment on BookReviewsConnection {\n  totalCount\n  edges {\n    node {\n      ...ReviewCardFragment\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  pageInfo {\n    prevPageToken\n    nextPageToken\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ReviewCardFragment on Review {\n  __typename\n  id\n  creator {\n    ...ReviewerProfileFragment\n    __typename\n  }\n  recommendFor\n  updatedAt\n  createdAt\n  spoilerStatus\n  lastRevisionAt\n  text\n  rating\n  shelving {\n    shelf {\n      name\n      webUrl\n      __typename\n    }\n    taggings {\n      tag {\n        name\n        webUrl\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    webUrl\n    __typename\n  }\n  likeCount\n  viewerHasLiked\n  commentCount\n}\n\nfragment ReviewerProfileFragment on User {\n  id: legacyId\n  imageUrlSquare\n  isAuthor\n  ...SocialUserFragment\n  textReviewsCount\n  viewerRelationshipStatus {\n    isBlockedByViewer\n    __typename\n  }\n  name\n  webUrl\n  contributor {\n    id\n    works {\n      totalCount\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment SocialUserFragment on User {\n  viewerRelationshipStatus {\n    isFollowing\n    isFriend\n    __typename\n  }\n  followersCount\n  __typename\n}\n",
    "variables": {
        "filters": {
            "resourceId": "kca://work/amzn1.gr.work.v1.lSjSf2r-G6D1advk_kunEg",
            "resourceType": "WORK",
        },
        "pagination": {"limit": 100},
    },
}

while True:
    data = requests.post(api_url, headers=headers, json=payload).json()

    for r in data["data"]["getReviews"]["edges"]:
        print(r["node"]["text"])
        print()

    pi = data["data"]["getReviews"]["pageInfo"]

    if not pi.get("nextPageToken"):
        break

    payload["variables"]["pagination"]["after"] = pi["nextPageToken"]

Prints:

...

This book is Awesome!

‘So take my hand now, Close your eyes and walk with me’. <br />I read this almost two years ago and yet it feels like it was only last week. It is one of my favourite books. <br /><br />I love Mia and mr kindly friendship and there banter. <br />Jay kristoff’s plot twist always have me by surprise, when Ashlin ... 

...

